# codeingiter - pass two json values from model to dropdown list in view

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter, select

I currently have a dropdown list that is being dynamically generated from my database with json. Currently the `value` of the select box and the `displayed text` are the same. both the json value being passed.

I want to adjust my model to return two json values to the dropdown list. one to be the `displayed` text and one to be the `value`.

How can I adjust json and my jquery script to populate the value with the field `idDelAddress` and the displayed text to be the field `address`

My Model is:

```
  function GetDeliveryAddressfromCustomer($q){

    $query = $this->db->query("
    select idDelAddress, address
    from [NFG_Live].[dbo].[Client]
    join
    [NFG_Live].[dbo].[_etblDelAddress]
    on
    [NFG_Live].[dbo].[_etblDelAddress].iAccountID=[NFG_Live].[dbo].[Client].DCLink
    where Name='$q'
      ");
        if($query->num_rows > 0){
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
                $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['address'])); 
                $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['idDelAddress'])); //I added this for second field. correct?

           }
           return $row_set;
        }
      }
```

My JQuery is:

```
$.post('GetDeliveryAddressfromCustomer', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) {     
$("#deliveryaddress").html('<option value=""></option>'); //or you could empty it or ignore this line
$.each(result, function(index, value) {
$("#deliveryaddress").append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>')
               });
              }
              , "json"  
              );
```

I am unsure how to adjust my model to pass 2 fields to the view.. In my view I am unsure how to call the secind json field.

so I am wanting to do this:
 `$("#deliveryaddress").append('<option value="'+idDelAddress_value+'">'+Address_value+'</option>')`

any advice is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need this, in your model make this change:

```
if($query->num_rows > 0){
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        $arr    = array(
                    "address"=>htmlentities(stripslashes($row['address'])),
                    "idDelAddress"=>htmlentities(stripslashes($row['idDelAddress']))
                  );
        $row_set[]  = $arr;
        //$row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['address'])); 
        //$row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['idDelAddress'])); //I added this for second field. correct?

   }
   return $row_set;
}
```

Now in your javascript where you loop, do something like this:

```
$(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result))).each(function() {  
     $("#deliveryaddress").append('<option value="'+this.idDelAddress+'">'+this.address+'</option>');
});
```

It's just an rough assumption. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is store both array in another array and json_encode() the variable while displaying the output

Model as

```
function GetDeliveryAddressfromCustomer($q){

    $query = $this->db->query("
    select idDelAddress, address
    from [NFG_Live].[dbo].[Client]
    join
    [NFG_Live].[dbo].[_etblDelAddress]
    on
    [NFG_Live].[dbo].[_etblDelAddress].iAccountID=[NFG_Live].[dbo].[Client].DCLink
    where Name='$q'
      ");
        if($query->num_rows > 0){
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
                $address[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['address'])); 
                $idDelAddressr[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['idDelAddress'])); //I added this for second field. correct?

           }
          $row_set['address'] = $address;
          $row_set['idDelAddress'] = $idDelAddress;
           return $row_set;
        }
      }
```

In your controller do something like this

```
function controller_fn(){
     $json_var = $this->your_model->GetDeliveryAddressfromCustomer($q);
     echo json_encode($json_var);
}
```

In your js you have to do something like this

```
$.post('GetDeliveryAddressfromCustomer', {data:selectedObj.value},function(result) {   
     var opt="";
     for(i=0;i<result.address.length;i++){
         opt += '<option value="'+result.idDelAddress+'">'+result.address(i)+'</option>'
     }
     $('#deliveryaddress').append(opt);

},"json");
```

you have make sure that your output is a valid json check [here](http://jsonlint.com/) and you may have also to know how to extract your json data.

Comment: Thanks Sathya, Appreciate the help. Model changes seem to work great but I am getting the error `result.address is not a function` line 76 which is `opt += '<option value="'+result.idDelAddress+'">'+result.address`+'</option>'` any ideas, thank you!

Comment: @Smudger it may because of your json variable structure can you show me your json output from that function or url your getting ?